# UFT crashes the .Net desktop application for framework 4.5 when we put spy on any of the object in application

Tags: .net, ms-word, add-in, qtp, hp-uft

We have customized Word addins which open some .Net-based windows. When I try to use the Object Spy on it, the whole application along with the word.exe process gets closed.

I think it is related to some .net framework version issue. Because after crashing I check the event viewer where I could see the error as "`.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5485 - Fatal Execution Engine Error`".

Could it be UFT 12 is not working well with.Net 4.5?

Comment: I think this should not happen. To further diagnose this, simplify the Word addin code until it is so trivial that you can post sample code here, while it still reproduces the problem for you. This gives a better chance to find out where the culprit is located. (In other words, create a self-contained, simple, correct example, see http://sscce.org/). Often, this already leads to enough insight that you either know what's wrong, or believe that you don't do anything wrong, the latter of which is a good starting point for getting a useful answer using a sscce in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The below steps may solve your problem.

1. Clean temp files --> cmd --> %temp% --> Delete all the files in this directory.
2. If you are testing the web application, then delete the temp files from browser.
3. Last but not the least, you may need to install add-ins for ur application. Need to do little research on it. You can find it on HP website.

Hope this would have solved your problem.